# double conditional rendering doesn't work

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a json data that I flatlist:

```
      ListDemande: [
    {
        "type" : 'gift' ,
        "etat" : 1,
        "titreTransaction": "عدد الوحدات",
        "contenuTrans": "400",
        "dateTrans": "2019-07-31 17:47:31"
    },
    {
        "type" : 'ba' ,
        "etat" : 1,
        "titreTransaction": "عدد الوحدات",
        "contenuTrans": "500",
        "dateTrans": "2019-07-31 17:31:35"
    },
    {
        "type" : 'gift' , // problem in this item
        "etat" : 0,
        "titreTransaction": "عدد الوحدات",
        "contenuTrans": "700",
        "dateTrans": "2019-07-24 11:53:21"
    },
    {
        "type" : 'gift' ,
        "etat" : 1,
        "titreTransaction": "عدد الوحدات",
        "contenuTrans": "1000",
        "dateTrans": "2019-07-01 16:18:03"
    },
    {
        "type" : 'ba' ,
        "etat" : 0,
        "titreTransaction": "عدد الوحدات",
        "contenuTrans": "200",
        "dateTrans": "2019-06-13 17:39:24"
    },

],
```

in my item I have to do a conditional redering like this to show icon of `gift` or  `ba`, it depend to the "type" and also a condition to indicate if this item is valid or not with "etat" that takes 1 or 0 and this is my approach :

```
const ic1 = <IconAD name="gift" size={hp('4%')}
              color= {
                demande.etat === 0 ?
                Colors.red :
                Colors.green
              }
              style={Styles.iconStyleBG}/>;
const ic2 = <IconAD name="tagso" size={hp('4.5%')}
            color= {
              demande.etat === 1 ?
              Colors.green :
              Colors.red
            }
            style={Styles.iconStyleBG}/>;


    let ic;
    if (demande.type === 'gift') {
        ic = ic1
    } else if (demande.type === 'ba'){
        ic = ic2
      }
const valideComp = <View style={Styles.container}>
    {ic}

    <View style={Styles.scoreContainer}>
      <View style={Styles.scoreValueContainer}>

        <Text style={[Styles.scoreUnityText, Styles.colorV]}>درهم</Text>
        <Text style={[Styles.scoreValueText, Styles.colorV]}>
        {demande.contenuTrans}
        </Text>
        <IconFA5 name="check" size={hp('2.6%')} color= {Colors.green} style={Styles.vIcStyle}/>


      </View>
    </View>
      <View style={Styles.dateTimeContainer}>
        <View style={Styles.dateContainer}>
          <Text style={Styles.dateText}>{date}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.TimeContainer}>
          <Text style={Styles.TimeText}>{time}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>;

const invalideComp = <View style={Styles.container}>
    {ic}
    <IconAD name="tagso" size={hp('4.5%')} color= {Colors.red} style={Styles.iconStyleBG}/>

    <View style={Styles.scoreContainer}>
      <View style={Styles.scoreValueContainer}>

        <Text style={[Styles.scoreUnityText, Styles.colorNv]}>درهم</Text>
        <Text style={[Styles.scoreValueText, Styles.colorNv]}>
        {demande.contenuTrans}
        </Text>
        <IconMCI name="timer-sand-full" size={hp('2.7%')} color= {Colors.red} style={Styles.vIcStyle}/>


      </View>
    </View>
      <View style={Styles.dateTimeContainer}>
        <View style={Styles.dateContainer}>
          <Text style={Styles.dateText}>{date}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.TimeContainer}>
          <Text style={Styles.TimeText}>{time}</Text>
          <Text style={Styles.TimeText}>{demande.type}</Text>
          <Text style={Styles.TimeText}>{demande.etat}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>;


    let comp;
    if (demande.etat === 1) {
        comp = valideComp
    } else if (demande.etat === 0){
        comp = invalideComp
      }
```

may be it's not a best approach since I am a beginner but logically it must work.

the probleme is that it works good for all item but not for this item :

[image]

it show me two icons in the same time if `"type" : "700"` and `"etat" : 0,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to have declared an additional `<IconAD name="tagso" />` under `invalideComp` despite declaring `ic` const previously. removing it should resolve the issue.

also, if there are only two conditions to manage, your code would be a lot cleaner if you use `else` instead of `else if` that would likely indicate a third condition.

```
let comp;
if (demande.etat === 1) {
  comp = valideComp
// } else if (demande.etat === 0){
} else {
  comp = invalideComp
}
```

**or**

```
let comp;
if (demande.etat === 1) {
  comp = valideComp
} else if (demande.etat === 0) {
  comp = invalideComp
} else {
  comp = <View />
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much I did not pay attention and thanks also for the other version of the code